# ecdsa は BQP に含まれる?

Tags: 暗号理論, 量子コンピュータ

ecdsa は、 rsa に代替するアルゴリズムとして使われています。 rsa は shor のアルゴリズムによって BQP であることが示されていますが、  ecdsa 暗号についてはどうなのでしょうか?

- BQP
- BQPよりも真に困難
- 不明?

Comment: いくつか正確でない点があるので指摘します。①ECDSA はデジタル署名のためのアルゴリズムであり、暗号ではありません。②BQP などの計算量クラスは[決定問題](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%B1%BA%E5%AE%9A%E5%95%8F%E9%A1%8C)を扱うための枠組みであるため、Yes / No で答えられるように問題を決める必要があります。このとき問題の作り方によって計算量が変わりうるので、注意が必要です。